# Going to and endless loop in my mac mini m1?

Tags: c#, .net, macos, visual-studio, artificial-intelligence

[image: what is going on please]

Could someone please check my code; there's an endless loop every time I run it on my Mac Mini M1, but seems fine under windows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WordGame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //this reads the dictionary.txt file in the bin folder
            string textFile = "dictionary.txt";

            if (File.Exists(textFile))
            {
                // Read a text file line by line.  
                List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(textFile).ToList();
                List<string> wordList = new List<string>();
                int wordLength = 0;
                string playAgain = "y";
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine("  WELCOME TO WORD GUESS GAME     ");
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("***************************************************************************************");
                    // it seems like the code will just loop here ... and it will never end
                    do
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter the length of word"); // Get the length  of word
                        try
                        {
                            wordLength = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("The Length of word enter must be in numbers"); // if the word is not number than return error
                            Console.WriteLine(" ");
                        }
                        int i = 0;
                        foreach (var line in lines)
                        {
                            if (line.Length == wordLength)
                            {
                                wordList.Add(line);
                            }
                        }
                    } while (wordList.Count == 0 && wordLength == 0);
                    // this loop will continue until the wordlength is not entered.
                    int totalGuess = 0;
                    do {
                        Console.Write("Enter the number of guesses in numbers:"); // get the number of guesses.
                        try
                        {
                            totalGuess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("invalid key enter ");
                        }
                    } while (totalGuess==0);
                    // repeat until the number of guesses are not entered
                
                    Console.Write("Do you want to display total number of words left. y/n :");
                    string displayTotal = Console.ReadLine(); // ask to whether to display the number of words or not
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    int guessLeft = totalGuess; // record total guesses left
                    var c = 0;
                    List<char> letterUsed = new List<char>(); // list of letter used
                    List<string> wordFamily = new List<string>(); // list of wordFamily
                    string word = "";
                    // loop for creating the empty word
                    for (int n = 0; n < wordLength; n++) 
                    {
                        word = word + "_";
                    }
                    char guess =' ';
                    do
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            // if the user enter the first guess remove all the words that have guess from wordFamily.
                            if(guess==' ') 
                            {
                                Console.Write("Enter the guess :");
                                guess = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                                wordList= wordList.Where(b=>!b.Contains(guess)).ToList();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.Write("Enter the guess :");
                                guess = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("The guess must be a character"); // guess must be character check.
                        }

                        //check if the guess is in letter used list
                        if (letterUsed.Contains(guess))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("already use this letter");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            letterUsed.Add(guess);
                            List<string> newWordList = new List<string>();
                            List<string> counter = new List<string>();
                            var h = wordList.Where(r => r.Contains(guess)).ToList(); //get all the letters that contain the guess letter.
                            if (h.Count() == 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Sorry there is no " + guess);
                                guessLeft--;
                                Console.WriteLine("You have guess " + guessLeft + " Left");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.Write("Letter used :"); //print the letter used
                                for (int l = 0; l < letterUsed.Count; l++)
                                {
                                    Console.Write(" " + letterUsed[l]);
                                }
                                Console.WriteLine("");
                                // The following loop creates the new wordFamily list 
                                //It will extract the list of words that contain the guess on the basis of following.
                                //The wordFamily that reveal the mininum clue will be selected.
                           
                                for (var t = 0; t < wordLength; t++)
                                {
                                    var N = wordList.Where(r => r.Count(b => b == guess) == t).ToList();
                                    for (var x = 0; x < wordLength; x++)
                                    {
                                        var g = N.Where(r => r.IndexOf(guess) == x).ToList();
                                        if (g.Count() > newWordList.Count())
                                        {
                                            newWordList = g;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                wordList = newWordList;
                                if (displayTotal.Trim() == "y")
                                {
                                    //print the words left.
                                    Console.Write("Words Left : ");
                                    foreach (var r in wordList)
                                    {
                                        Console.Write(" " + r);
                                    }
                                    Console.WriteLine(" ");
                                }
                                StringBuilder wordInList = new StringBuilder(wordList.FirstOrDefault());
                                StringBuilder wordGuess = new StringBuilder(word);

                                //create the word with guessed letter and dashes
                                for (var w = 0; w < wordInList.Length; w++)
                                {
                                    if (wordInList[w].Equals(guess))
                                    {
                                        wordGuess[w] = guess;
                                    }
                                }
                                word = wordGuess.ToString();
                                Console.WriteLine("Word :" + wordGuess);
                                Console.WriteLine("There is copy of " + guess);
                                Console.WriteLine("");
                            }
                        }
                        c++;
                    } while (guessLeft != 0 && word.Contains("_"));

                    Console.WriteLine(" ");
                    if (guessLeft == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You lose.The word was " + wordList.Select(r => r).FirstOrDefault());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You won!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(" ");
                    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to Play Again");
                    playAgain = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(" ");
                } while (playAgain.Trim() == "y");

                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine("Thank you");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File does not exist. Change the path");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: Try to print the exception message into the output. It may give you some clue on what is going on.
`
catch(Exception ex)
                            {
Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                                Console.WriteLine("The Length of word enter must be in numbers"); // if the word is not number than return error
                                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                            }
`

Comment: You might want to consider breaking this down a little into more manageable chunks of code.  For instance, take out the contents of the `do...while` loops and turn them into separate private functions, etc.  There's a lot of pasta in there!